is to possible to call annotation interfaces' default methods?
Given an annotation interface such as
@Documented
@Target(ElementType.PARAMETER)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface ValidFileType {

    String[] value() default {
        MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN_VALUE,
        MediaType.APPLICATION_PDF_VALUE,
        MediaType.IMAGE_GIF_VALUE
    };

    String message() default "{com.example.invalidFileType}";

    Class<?>[] groups() default {};

    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
}

Is it possible to get the default list of file types from outside the interface, i.e. the string array returned by value()?

Yeap, you need to use reflection to do so, here is a simple example (note that I removed the MediaType as I don't know from which library you are importing it)
@Documented
@Target(ElementType.PARAMETER)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface ValidFileType {
    String[] value() default {
        "value 1",
        "value 2",
        "value 3"
    };
}

Here is a test class to read it (I added the imports)
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.util.Arrays;
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws NoSuchMethodException, SecurityException {
        Class<?> annotationClass = ValidFileType.class;
        Method valueMethod = annotationClass.getMethod("value");
        //You might need to change this line 
        //a bit to convert the MediaType to string (just toString might work)        
        String[] defaultValues = (String[]) valueMethod.getDefaultValue();
        System.out.println("Valid file types: " + Arrays.toString(defaultValues));
    }
}

It then prints:
Valid file types: [value 1, value 2, value 3]

